# How to remove the keyboard layout icon from the Panel notification area in Unity?

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator, language-support, notification-area

First let me show a screenshot of my Panel notification area.

[image]

I just want to remove the `En` icon from there. How do I do it? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open the system settings:

   [image]
2. Open the Keyboard icon:

   [image]
3. Open the Layout Settings and select text entry:

   [image]
4. Deselect the "Show current input source in the menu bar"

   [image]

Comment: Why doesn't a similar option exist for the messages icon in the menu bar? I'd like to remove it, but there's no obvious way to do so. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/562483/how-to-edit-menu-bar-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts