# How to edit the Panel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: indicator, customization, panel

I want to remove the mail icon from the Panel is it possible to do that? I tried to find some solution but all was for the old version of Ubuntu.

[image],

Answer (score 3):

In /etc/xdg/autostart you should see a .desktop file for every indicator, its name will begin with 'indicator'. 
Here's an example of a bluetooth indicator (indicator-bluetooth.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Indicator Bluetooth
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-bluetooth
```

Open the .desktop file that corresponds to the indicator you want to remove, and find the 'NoDisplay' line and change the value to true (as in my Bluetooth example).
If the line does not already exist, you can add it.

Comment: There should be a nice gui way to do this, like old gnome 2, or xfce, mate, cinnamon... a right-click & remove?

Comment: I add a screen shoot, I add the line, but the icon is still there :( http://postimg.org/image/j8o87fa4b/

Comment: Did you try logging out and in again?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I am having the same issue and I tried the recommended steps including logging out and logging back in, but it didn't work for me. Appreciate any ideas.